# XPages Dojo HorizontalSlider onchange

Tags: dojo, slider, xpages

I've been looking for a couple of days now on how to implement a Dojo HorizontalSlider control on my xpage. I've found about 4 different examples of code. I have also tried over and over to simply drag the control from the the Dojo Form list of controls and adjust the properties. I can't get it to work no matter how simple I try to make it.
I want to slide between 0 and 10 and capture the integer into a Edit box control.

Does anyone have an example of this and the code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for a slider for values between 0 and 10 which writes the current integer value to an edit box on change:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:djHorizontalSlider
        id="djHorizontalSlider1"
        value="#{viewScope.sliderNumber}"
        style="margin: 5px;width:200px; height: 20px;"
        minimum="0"
        maximum="10">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber
                integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xe:djSliderRule
            id="djSliderRule2"
            style="height:5px;"
            count="11"
            container="bottomDecoration">
        </xe:djSliderRule>
        <xe:djSliderRuleLabels
            id="djSliderRuleLabels2"
            container="bottomDecoration"
            style="height:10px;font-size:75%;color:gray;">
            <li>0</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
        </xe:djSliderRuleLabels>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onChange"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="inputText1">
            <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                 viewScope.inputNumber = viewScope.sliderNumber
            }]]></xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:djHorizontalSlider>
    <xp:inputText
        id="inputText1"
        value="#{viewScope.inputNumber}">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber
                integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

On event `onChange` a partial refresh is executed for edit field "inputText1". Slider's current value gets converted to an integer value and is written to `viewScope.sliderNumber`. From there it is copied to `viewScope.inputNumber` which is bound to the edit field. After partial refresh the value is visible in edit field.

Comment: dsfdsfd dfgdrgdfgdrgdr

Comment: sorry, I did not mean to comment yet. I'm getting the same result as when I tried to implement a slider step by step. It's going 100% width with commas and hash marks and labels all over the place.Not sure how to display a screenshot of this, but I checked the code carefully.

Comment: in the design, it looks perfect. fyi, this is on a 9.01 domino server and using 9.01 Designer

Comment: My example is a complete XPage. Does it work for you if you use the XPage without any changes?

Comment: i will try it now. in the meantime, here is pic of it displayed on the web. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byqhr3IZsEbqRXlQWUYzWkJJdHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It does work as it's own xpage. I will have to keep combing through the code. Besides these two line, there are a lot of other lines/attributes in the view tag
     xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
     xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"

Comment: It works as long as it is not inside a table cell. Any ideas on how to make it work inside a table?

Comment: Happy New Year. It does work in a table cell as well. It has to be something else what breaks the slider. Just add peace by peace from you XPage to the example XPage and look when in breaks.

Comment: Have a look at the table or table cell css/class properties.